# How to calculate current DAI Savings Rate

Tags: dai, makerdao

I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/makerdao/developerguides/blob/master/mcd/intro-rate-mechanism/intro-rate-mechanism.md#intro-to-the-rate-mechanism) on the topic but still don't get how I can calculate the current DAI Savings Rate myself.

The current `dsr` value is stored in the [pot contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x197E90f9FAD81970bA7976f33CbD77088E5D7cf7#readContract). At time of this writing it amounts to `1000000000000000000000000000`. I think I have to divide this value by the `RAY`, which is a `1` followed by 27 zeroes (`1000000000000000000000000000`). So the `dsr` and `RAY` are equal at the moment.

Next, I have to take the result of this operation (which is 1) and power it to the number of seconds per year (`31536000`). Obviously this equals to 1 again. So does this mean the current rate is set to 1 percent? It should really amount to zero at the moment.

Another problem I have with this calculation is that once the `dsr` changes to a weird value, then taking the power of seconds per year might take a really long time to calculate.

Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the calculation is actually correct. The result `1` is the amount by which the funds would be multiplied. So in order to get the percentage I would have to calculate the following:

`100 * ((dsr / ray)^secondsPerYear) - 100`, which equals to `0` at the moment of this writing.